# Add link on edit form for activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I need to add a link/button in the middle of the form in ActiveAdmin. I try to add action for has_multiple fields but it doesn't work:

```
form
 ..

 f.has_many :colors, sortable: :position, sortable_start: 1 do |a|
  a.input :name
  a.action :cancel, :as => :link, :url => "/path"
 end
end
```

Comment: Did you check [https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#nested-resources] ? What is the link supposed to do? If you want a 'delete/destroy' checkbox for the nested_resource it should be coverer by AA itself. Don't forget to setup your models with the ``accepts_nested_atrributes``, ``allow_destroy => true`` and set the ``permit_params``.

Comment: It's custom action. Not destroy.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
f.has_many :colors, sortable: :position, sortable_start: 1 do |a|
  a.input :name
  div do
    link_to("My custom action", custom_path(:some_parameter => a.object.id), :method => :post)
  end
end
```